# Android Jetpack Compose using same elevation value

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, android-elevation

[image: xml result]

Hi, I want to migrate my apps to android jetpack compose and create custom card like this. But, when I try to using my trick on xml (using same elevation value) to create shadow around the card, I can't generate the same result.

How can this be achieved using jetpack compose?

Comment: Post your code. Are you using M2 or M3?

Comment: Share your code